# Mobile broadband slow to be detected

Tags: 11.04, network-manager, connection, broadband

**-- UPDATE 1**: [relevant syslog lines](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/625429/).

**-- UPDATE 2**: a step further. I was able to solve the `GSM modem enable failed: (32) SIM PIN required` loop specifying the PIN in Network manager > Edit connections... > Mobile broadband > Edit > Mobile broadband > PIN.

**Original question**

I'm facing a pretty annoying issue with a **multimode GPRS/EDGE/UMTS/HSDPA USB internet key** I use for internet access, product **ONDA WCDMA Technologies MSM**. OS is Ubuntu Natty 11.04 64-bit.

The application asking me to enter the PIN starts only after some minutes the key is plugged in; time varies from immediately to 5 minutes and more. I try to trigger the recognition killing Network Manager applet `nm-applet` and restarting it, but I'm not sure it helps. I also see there is an utility called `/usr/bin/modem-manager` but I'm not able to run it (provided it could be useful, as `man modem-manager` gives nothing).

I'd like the key to be detected as soon as I plug it in, do you have any hint? I hate to say so but on Windows it takes only few seconds and the dongle is recognized (using product manufacturer dial in software).

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maintainer of NetworkManager explained the problem using these words:

> There are certain modems for which the
>   firmware simply doesn't respond to
>   serial setup packets sent on certain
>   interfaces, which cause the kernel to
>   wait for a while before timing out.

Just in case you are experiencing a similar issue I **sincerely** suggest you to report it on [NM mailing list](http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/networkmanager-list), they won't miss to help. I got a patch and now the device is recognized in less than 60 seconds.

And bonus, the fix will be submitted to the mainstream kernel for everyone's benefit.

Reference: [the full thread](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-June/msg00097.html).

Comment: Can you please explain the process of mailing them in detail ? I've a ZTE modem and it takes 2 minutes to connect.

Comment: Go to [this page](http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/networkmanager-list) and subscribe to the list. You will be sent an email to confirm the subscription. After you have confirmed you can send regular mails to the list using this address: networkmanager-list@gnome.org. Describe carefully the issue and someone will likely help you.