# How do I compile a kernel module?

Tags: kernel, 64-bit, compiling, source-code, kernel-modules

A good man on NetworkManager mailinglist provided [a patch](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-June/msg00226.html) that hopefully would solve an issue I'm experiencing related to [slow mobile broadband detection on Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48378/mobile-broadband-slow-to-be-detected). I'd really like to check the patch but I can't figure out how to do this.

As a starting point I have uncompressed `/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.38/linux-source-2.6.38.tar.bz2` and applied the patch to `/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.38/drivers/usb/serial/options.c`, but now I'm stuck.

**How do I recompile the module?** Possibly just the module, not the whole kernel and the other unmodified modules. Links to good docs are appreciated as well.

I already reconfigured and recompiled a kernel in the past (though the procedure looked a bit obscure to me...) so all the involved software should be in place.

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I build a single in-tree kernel module?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/) is very informative about kernel modules.

If you are a 100% newbie on this topic like I am/was and want to understand something more, it's the case to query Google for further delvings. Otherwise LKMPG (!) is enough to get the result. Specifically, the section [2.2 Compiling Kernel Modules](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html) is the direct and detailed answer to my question.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

- To build the **final module images** in a directory, you can use the `M=` argument for your `make` command:

  make M=drivers/usb/serial

This will build all the needed files in that directory and link the final module images.

- To build **only a specific file** in the kernel tree, just pass it as the argument to `make`:

  make drivers/usb/serial/visor.ko

The build system will build all needed files for the visor.ko kernel module, and do the final link to create the module.