# How do I build a single in-tree kernel module?

Tags: kernel, modules

The linux-source-... has a module which is disabled in the config /boot/config-3.4-trunk-686-pae so that it is not part of linux-image-... (This is on Debian, but the solution should be the same for Ubuntu, or?), e.g.

```
# CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_USB is not set
```

How would one compile just that kernel module, so that it can be used with the distributed kernel?

The respective linux-source-... package is already installed, uncompressed and linked to /usr/src/linux. /boot/config-3.4-trunk-686-pae is copied to /usr/src/linux/.config and modified with

```
CONFIG_CAN_PEAK_USB=m
```

With

```
make
make modules
```

it is possible to compile the kernel and all modules. But how would one compile only that specific single module?

(Note: also the kernel needs to be compiled before, otherwise you get the following error: `no symbol version for module_layout`)

Comment: please close as duplicate of 14627. answer of user 'Radu C' answers the question.

Comment: Did you try `depmod -a` before `modbrobe`?

Comment: consider following article too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744087/how-to-recompile-just-a-single-kernel-module/44204152#44204152

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had the same problem. I assume that you need not only to copy .config but also Module.symvers

my steps to compile module ft1000 (running Debian Wheeze 7.1.0; kernel 3.2.0-4-686-pae):

```
aptitude install linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae
aptitude install linux-source-3.2
cd /usr/src/
tar xjf linux-source-3.2.tar.bz2
cd /usr/src/linux-source-3.2
cp ../linux-headers-3.2.0-4-686-pae/Module.symvers .
make oldconfig # it copies .config to ./
vi .config # enable ft1000 module: CONFIG_FT1000=m
make prepare # setup FT1000 as module
make modules_prepare
make SUBDIRS=scripts/mod
make SUBDIRS=drivers/staging/ft1000/ft1000-usb modules
cp drivers/staging/ft1000/ft1000-usb/ft1000.ko /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-686-pae/kernel
/drivers/staging/
depmod
modprobe ft1000
```

Comment: I'm not sure if SUBDIRS is still correct. It was ignored for me. After reading https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt I tried using `make M=/path/to/module` which seemed to work.

Comment: Iam trying to modify a different module (is just adding a USB ID to an existent module) when I compile it I get no errors but when I insert it I get Invalid module format  why?!

Answer (score 16):

From within the top-level source directory, simply give make the path to the module name or module directory, e.g.:

```
make drivers/net/can/usb/peak_usb/
```

or for a simpler example (Intel e1000 Ethernet driver):

```
make drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000/e1000.ko
```

Comment: Just doing:
`make  drivers/net/can/usb/peak_usb/pcan_usb.ko`
did only build pcan_usb.o.

Doing `make  drivers/net/can/usb/peak_usb/ && make  drivers/net/can/usb/peak_usb/pcan_usb.ko`
compiles it, but insmod complains `Error: could not insert module drivers/net/can/usb/peak_usb/peak_usb.ko: Invalid module format`. dmesg: `peak_usb: no symbol version for module_layout`

Comment: Are you running that specific kernel, and have you already compiled the kernel once? Please try with `modprobe` also.

Comment: I am running the packaged kernel. Compiling the complete kernel works. but I am trying to not compile the complete kernel, just the specific kernel module. Is there a make target that 'prepares' a single module compilation? modprobe shows the same error.

Comment: According to [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744087/how-to-recompile-just-a-single-kernel-module) you can just use `make modules SUBDIRS=drivers/net/can/usb/peak_usb` or any other subdir.
It works fine here.

Comment: If you find new driver still used old version, sometimes you need run `make clean && make mrproper` before build.

Answer (score 4):

As simple as : (this example illustrate ft1000 driver, this should take just few minutes if not instants)

```
cd /usr/src/kernel-sources
make SUBDIRS=drivers/staging/ft1000/ft1000-usb modules
# Enable the ft1000 module: CONFIG_FT1000=m  on the config with 
make xconfig # or "make menuconfig" then save
make prepare
make modules_prepare
make SUBDIRS=scripts/mod
make SUBDIRS=drivers/staging/ft1000/ft1000-usb modules
make SUBDIRS=drivers/staging/ft1000/ft1000-usb modules_install
```

You can then load the module with `modprobe` after `depmod`

Note : depending on the module dependency you may need to rebuild the kernel entirely

Comment: +1 Because this approach can be used in any `make` projects, not only Linux kernel.

Answer (score 4):

- To build the **final module images** in a directory, you can use the `M=` argument for your `make` command:

  make M=drivers/usb/serial

This will build all the needed files in that directory and link the final module images.

- To build **only a specific file** in the kernel tree, just pass it as the argument to `make`:

  make drivers/usb/serial/visor.ko

The build system will build all needed files for the visor.ko kernel module, and do the final link to create the module.