# Compiling custom in-tree module

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling, realtek

I'd like to recompile one of the wifi modules, namely drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.3.

My kernel version :

`Linux fisk 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have the necessary headers in linux-headers-4.10.0-38-generic as well as the linux source in /usr/src/linux-source-4.10.0

I can build the module just fine in `/usr/src/linux-source-4.10.0` if I do make -j8 SUBDIRS=drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/, however the vermagic doesn't match that of my kernel and as a result the module cannot be loaded:

`modinfo drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu//rtl8xxxu.ko | grep vermagic
vermagic:       4.10.17 SMP mod_unload`

As a result when loading I get in dmesg:

```
rtl8xxxu: version magic '4.10.17 SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload '
```

So my question is what is the correct way to build the module and being able to load it on my kernel?

Comment: I already read the given answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module

However, it's producing a driver with invalid vermagic

Comment: Isn’t rtl8xxxu already included in kernel version 4.10? You may only need a slight tweak. Please post the result of: lsmod | grep rtl. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Is secureboot enable on your system?

Comment: Secure boot is not enabled. rtl8xxxu is part of the kernel, however it's missing a commit which adds the usb vendor/product ids for my product.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I answered my question. The command which I needed to execute was :

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=/home/foo/projects/kernel/linux-hwe-4.10.0/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu/
```

After that doing modinfo shows the correct thing and the module can be inserted:

```
modinfo /home/foor/projects/kernel/linux-hwe-4.10.0/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8xxxu//rtl8xxxu.ko | grep vermagic
vermagic:       4.10.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload
```